# Color image segmentation using java

Tags: java

I am trying to segmentig an image using color segmentation i have found some code over the internet but it ony works for yellow and green colour i have been trying to implement it for other colors but it won't work here is the code.I am using BoofCV library

```
public class ExampleSegmentColor 
{
public static void printClickedColor( final BufferedImage image ) {
    ImagePanel gui = new ImagePanel(image);
    gui.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            float[] color = new float[3];
            int rgb = image.getRGB(e.getX(),e.getY());
            ColorHsv.rgbToHsv((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF, (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF, rgb & 0xFF, color);
            System.out.println("H = " + color[0]+" S = "+color[1]+" V = "+color[2]);

            showSelectedColor("Selected",image,color[0],color[1]);
        }
    });

    ShowImages.showWindow(gui,"Color Selector");
}

public static void showSelectedColor( String name , BufferedImage image , float hue , float saturation ) {
    Planar<GrayF32> input = ConvertBufferedImage.convertFromMulti(image,null,true,GrayF32.class);
    Planar<GrayF32> hsv = input.createSameShape();

    // Convert into HSV
    ColorHsv.rgbToHsv_F32(input,hsv);

    // Euclidean distance squared threshold for deciding which pixels are members of the selected set
    float maxDist2 = 0.4f*0.4f;

    // Extract hue and saturation bands which are independent of intensity
    GrayF32 H = hsv.getBand(0);
    GrayF32 S = hsv.getBand(1);

    // Adjust the relative importance of Hue and Saturation.
    // Hue has a range of 0 to 2*PI and Saturation from 0 to 1.
    float adjustUnits = (float)(Math.PI/2.0);

    BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(input.width,input.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for( int y = 0; y < hsv.height; y++ ) {
        for( int x = 0; x < hsv.width; x++ ) {

            float dh = UtilAngle.dist(H.unsafe_get(x,y),hue);
            float ds = (S.unsafe_get(x,y)-saturation)*adjustUnits;

            float dist2 = dh*dh + ds*ds;
            if( dist2 <= maxDist2 ) {
                output.setRGB(x,y,image.getRGB(x,y));
            }
        }
    }

    ShowImages.showWindow(output,"Showing "+name);
}

public static void main( String args[] ) {
    BufferedImage image = UtilImageIO.loadImage(UtilIO.pathExample("sunflowers.jpg"));

    // Let the user select a color
    printClickedColor(image);
    // Display pre-selected colors
    showSelectedColor("Yellow",image,1f,1f);
    showSelectedColor("Green",image,1.5f,0.65f);
}
```

}

Comment: show completete (i.e. capable to compile) but shortest code presenting a problem.

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly ckeck asap.